# JAX-RS: Automatic serialization of LocalDate to JSON not working (json-b) - Liberty profile 19.0.0.6

Tags: java, json, websphere

I'm using websphere liberty profile 19.0.0.6, with the following features enabled:

```
<feature>jsonb-1.0</feature>
<feature>jsonp-1.1</feature>
```

To me, that would be sufficient to have the automatic serialization to JSON considering the default string format for LocalDate/LocalDateTime (yyyy-MM-dd) when returning from a restful web service.

For example, considering that dto is a LocalDate with the value (2016, 11, 10):

```
Response.ok().entity(dto).build();
```

That returns a JSON like the following:

```
{
"year": 2016,
"month": "NOVEMBER",
"chronology": {
"id": "ISO",
"calendarType": "iso8601"
},
"era": "CE",
"monthValue": 11,
"dayOfMonth": 10,
"dayOfYear": 315,
"dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
"leapYear": true
}
```

Instead of returning:

```
"2016-11-10"
```

Do I have to do anything else to enable json-b to automatically do the work of conversion?

*Code copied from the incorrectly created answer:*

```
public abstract class BaseDTO implements Serializable {

    // id and version fields with respective getter and setter

}



public class RuleDTO extends BaseDTO {

    java.time.LocalDate startDate;
    java.time.LocalDate endDate;

    // getters and setters for startDate and endDate

}
```

when the RuleDTO is serialized, I don't get the correct formatting which I expected.

Comment: can you upload the code for your DTO object? Normally a `java.time.LocalDate` should convert to the JSON String `2016-11-10` like you are expecting.

Comment: What "base feature" of liberty are you using for your app? javaee7/webprofile7? javaee8/webprofile8? If you are on javaee7, you have to provide a converter (a few lines of Java, I can provide the code...) as java.time classes are newer than javaee7...